# How to capture the time from this string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have this string
`<td>pending since<br/>Thu 15 Sep 2022 11:43:49 PM UTC </td>`
And I want to capture the "Thu 15 Sep 2022 11:43:49 PM UTC" in a regex.

I've tried `re.compile('<td>pending since<br/>* </td>')` To no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I might use a regex find approach here seeking the timestamp:

```py
inp = "<td>pending since<br/>Thu 15 Sep 2022 11:43:49 PM UTC </td>"
ts = re.findall(r'\b\w{3} \d{1,2} \w{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M \w+', inp)
print(ts)  # ['Thu 15 Sep 2022 11:43:49 PM UTC']
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the way!

```
import re

time = re.findall(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', test_string_goes_here)[0]
print(time)
```